# Equal sign does not show up in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm doing my beamer now and if I write the equal sign (=) whether it is in math mode or not, it does not appear in the output. Help? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{a}

= aaaaaaa

$ = $ 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

the output is

> aaaaaaaaaa

no equal sign

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately, my crystal bowl is really cloudy today. :-( Could you post some example code, ideally in the form of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), that generates the problem behavior?

Comment: I guess your system is a little bit outdated? With current MiKTeX 2.9 your mwe comiles and shows both equal signs ... Which distrivution do you use, which version? Type `pdflatex --version` in your terminal/console and add the message to your question please.

Comment: Like Kurt, I experience no issues when compiling your MWE. Please tell us which TeX distribution and which operating system you use.